# Map(coordinateRegion: , showsUserLocation: ) deprecated in iOS 17.0

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, ios17

Any ideas of how to replace this call? It was blindingly useful and has now been deprecated in iOS 17.0.

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
```

This was being fed via:

```
enum MapDetails {
     static let startingLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: GlobalVariables.latitude, longitude: GlobalVariables.longitude)
     static let defaultSpan      = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: GlobalVariables.span, longitudeDelta: GlobalVariables.span)
}

final class LocationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager:  CLLocationManager?
@Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: MapDetails.startingLocation, span: MapDetails.defaultSpan)

...
```

The yellow warning is:

> 'init(coordinateRegion:interactionModes:showsUserLocation:userTrackingMode:)' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: Use Map initializers that take a MapContentBuilder instead.

Is there an obvious replacement that I have overlooked?

Comment: The error message clearly tells you want to do. How about you "use `Map` initializers that take a `MapContentBuilder` instead"?

Comment: Apparently the new @MapContentBuilder macro is covered some in the [WWDC 2023 Meet MapKit for SwiftUI video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043/)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`init(position:bounds:interactionModes:scope:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map/4231673-init) initialiser instead. This takes a binding of [`NapCameraPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapcameraposition), so you should change the type in the view model accordingly.

Note that you can create a `MapCameraPosition` from a `MKCoordinateRegion` by using [`MapCameraPosition.region(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapcameraposition/4231717-region).

To show the user's position, use a [`UserAnnotation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/userannotation)

```
Map(position: $viewModel.region) {
    UserAnnotation()
}
```

Comment: Hi - has the MapCameraPosition replaced the UserLocation?  So will @State var myLocation: MapCameraPosition = .automatic give me my current location? 

Is there an example that I can work through that gives the user location? All that I have found use explicit locations. And haven't been able to work it backwards from the WWDC video that was my first port of call.

Your notes are highly condensed and I am sure spot on.

Comment: The WWDC overview doesn't show you how to programatically get the users, location, it just adds MapUserLocationButton() to the Map(). Is there a way to programatically press this?

Comment: @EdwardHasted Oh you want to *move* the map to the user's location? I think `.automatic` should work then. You can also use `.userLocation(fallback: .automatic)` or similar. Of course, make sure you request the location permissions first.

Comment: @EdwardHasted You seem confused. Are you aware that I'm talking about the `MapCameraPosition` value of `$viewModel.region`? Set that initially to those values. If we are still not on the same page, I suggest that you post a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: From App Developer the approach appears to be add @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .userLocation(followsHeading: true, fallback: .automatic) and then Map(position: $position) {
            UserAnnotation()
        } but this generates the "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" message.

Comment: @EdwardHasted Are you using the latest Xcode beta? I don't think that is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map initializer that take a MapContentBuilder instead.

```
@Published var position = MapCameraPosition.region(MKCoordinateRegion(center: MapDetails.startingLocation, span: MapDetails.defaultSpan))
```

**MapCameraPosition**
a structure that describes how to position the map’s camera within the map.

```
 Map(position: $viewModel.position)
```